# Why is the last string in the file is printed twice on the screen while retrieving the data?

Tags: c, file-management

I have written the following C code to write five names to a text file and print the same on the monitor. While reading the data from the file, the last string is printed twice on the screen..But why..

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
  FILE *fp1, *fp2, *fp3;
  char name[10];
  int n,c;
  clrscr();

  printf("How many names..\n");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  fp1 = fopen("source.txt", "w");

  while( n > 0 )
  {
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Enter the name\n");
    gets(name);
    fprintf(fp1,"%s\n", name);
    n--;
  }

  fclose(fp1);
  fp1 = fopen("source.txt", "r");
  printf(" You entered the following names\n");

  while( !feof(fp1) )
  {
    fscanf(fp1, "%s", name);
    printf("%s\t", name);
  }

  getch();
}
```

Comment: `while( !feof(fp1) )
  {
    fscanf(fp1, "%s", name);
    printf("%s\t", name);
  }` --> `while( EOF!=fscanf(fp1, "%s", name) )
  {
    printf("%s\t", name);
  }`

Comment: `foef` is only set AFTER a "failed" read attempt. Full answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: Yup - knew what this was from the title:(

Comment: C does not look into the future on`FILE` input.  End-of-file is not flagged until after it occurs.  So check the return value of `fscanf()` instead.  Also 2) do not use `gets()`  use `fgets()` or `getline()`  3) do not use `fflush(stdin);` - not needed 3) check return values from `scanf()` and family.

Answer (score -1):

Because you didn't read manual for feof.

The C version feof didn't automatically return true when you are at the end of file. It will return true after you attempt reading something only to find no more data to read.

Other language's "feof" may be a little easier to use. For example, Perl's eof will return 1 if the next read on FILEHANDLE will return end of file ...

Comment: Why can't I request beginners to read manual for basic functions?